# How to vertically align an element to the bottom of another element without absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical navigation menu, with a picture next to it. So now the navigation menu and the pic are vertically aligned to the top. I want it to be bottom, like, the navigation menu to vertically finish at the same point where the image does. How do I go about doing this with using absolute positioning?

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
 </ul>

 <img src="pic.jpg">
```

CSS:

```
 ul {
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
 }

 ul li {
    padding-top: 5px;
 }

 ul li a {
    background: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 35px;
    font-size: 20px;
 }

 img {
    width: 230px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
 }
```

I don't want to use absolute positions, because the image is supposed to interconnect with the navigation menu (It's supposed to be a png picture of a guy with the buttons coming from behind him) so I'm worried it might mess things up if someone had a different font sizing in their browser.

Comment: Flexbox will do the job.

Comment: i think you have vertical-alignment:bottom in css you can try out

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table;` to achieve this.

Create a wrapping element for the `ul` and `img` and give it `display: table;`. `ul` and `img` should have `display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom;` then. You don't need `float: left;` on `ul` or `img` either if you do it this way.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xq6SY/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Reviews</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <img src="pic.jpg">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
}
ul {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
ul li {
    padding-top: 5px;
}
ul li a {
    background: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 35px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
img {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code even though I pressed it to the bottom of the screen))   [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ayxgr)

```
<div class="page-wrap">



</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
 </ul>

 <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300">
</footer>


* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  /*height: 142px; */
}
.site-footer {
  background: white;
}
 ul {
    /*float: left;*/
    text-align: right;
   display:inline-block;
 }

 ul li {
    padding-top: 5px;
 }

 ul li a {
    background: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 35px;
    font-size: 20px;
 }

     img {
    width: 230px;
    height: auto;
    display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:bottom;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nZ35/)

### css

```
ul, img { display:inline-block; vertical-align:bottom;}
```

**** Important**: Don't forget to remove your floats, and add padding:0; margin:0; to your UL.
(look at the fiddle)